# Reverse sign (+/-) by looping through multiple matrices in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a list with 2 matrices and I would like to reverse the sign of each value (turn + to - and vice versa). I tried it for a single matrix and it worked. But how do I loop over multiple matrices?

```r
set.seed(20)
data.matrix1 <- matrix(nrow=100, ncol=10)
colnames(data.matrix1) <- c(
  paste("PC", 1:10, sep=""))
rownames(data.matrix1) <- paste("food", 1:100, sep="")
for (i in 1:100) {
  wt.values <- rpois(10, lambda=sample(x=10:1000, size=5))

  data.matrix1[i,] <- c(wt.values)
}

head(data.matrix1)
#>       PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4  PC5 PC6 PC7 PC8 PC9 PC10
#> food1 940 729 294 465  956 862 717 274 587  974
#> food2 451 846 196 511  474 447 833 216 515  475
#> food3 384 104 935  66  939 428 107 991  55  937
#> food4  66 535 295 857 1052  63 526 327 787  955
#> food5  70 633 429 488  316  88 616 451 511  316
#> food6 874 824  12 646  522 844 875  10 650  530

set.seed(50)
data.matrix2 <- matrix(nrow=100, ncol=10)
colnames(data.matrix2) <- c(
  paste("PC", 1:10, sep=""))
rownames(data.matrix2) <- paste("food", 1:100, sep="")
for (i in 1:100) {
  wt.values <- rpois(10, lambda=sample(x=10:1000, size=5))

  data.matrix2[i,] <- c(wt.values)
}

head(data.matrix2)
#>       PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4 PC5 PC6 PC7 PC8 PC9 PC10
#> food1 666 406 198 750 508 719 454 199 748  507
#> food2 614 243 596 149 716 689 234 620 130  685
#> food3 182 589 141  59 735 210 591 132  32  727
#> food4 680 678 881 693  39 685 668 815 756   41
#> food5 505 483 248  48  85 505 460 271  46  103
#> food6 443 164 300 653  54 458 135 298 694   56

matrices <-list(data.matrix1, data.matrix2)



# Reverse sign: single matrix
data.matrix1[sapply(data.matrix1, is.numeric)] <- data.matrix1[sapply(data.matrix1, is.numeric)] * -1

head(data.matrix1)
#>        PC1  PC2  PC3  PC4   PC5  PC6  PC7  PC8  PC9 PC10
#> food1 -940 -729 -294 -465  -956 -862 -717 -274 -587 -974
#> food2 -451 -846 -196 -511  -474 -447 -833 -216 -515 -475
#> food3 -384 -104 -935  -66  -939 -428 -107 -991  -55 -937
#> food4  -66 -535 -295 -857 -1052  -63 -526 -327 -787 -955
#> food5  -70 -633 -429 -488  -316  -88 -616 -451 -511 -316
#> food6 -874 -824  -12 -646  -522 -844 -875  -10 -650 -530
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: A matrix can hold only one data type. `is.numeric` is not necessary. Can't you just do `matrices <- lapply(matrices, "-")`?

Answer (score 1):

You can change all the elements of the matrix at once:

```r
data.matrix1 <- -data.matrix1
```

If your matrices are in a list as in your sample code you can use `lapply` to apply a function that changes the sign to each matrix:

```r
matrices <- lapply(matrices, function(x) -x)
```

Comment: Why not `lapply(matrices, "-")` as in the comment from Roland?

Comment: Both solutions are fine. In my opinion if you see `function(x) -x` it's easier to imagine how to customize the function to do something else and therefore it may be useful to other people with a slightly different problem.